# Field extraction in fixed width file and validating format

Tags: linux, awk

I am writing a poc for a fixed width file to extract a particular field and checking its format . But the both giving me validation failed . can you please help me to point out the issue

in code i am trying to substr the email id and trimming for space and validating the format

code

```
awk -v m=16 -v p=13 -v 'n=[a-z]+@gmail.com' '
{ 
  c=substr($0,m,p)
  sub(" +$", "", c)
  c !~ "^" n "$"
  printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0> "/dev/stderr"
  count++
}
END {print count}' BNC_fixedwidth.txt
```

Input file

```
10027  20033t  abc@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, and what happens instead? Did you perhaps intend to test the result of `c !~ "^" n "$"` in a conditional of some sort (`if (c !~ "^" n "$") {...}`) ?

Comment: Expected is  the code has to extract the email from the line and validate the format using input regex function . So i did substr , then trimmed spaces and trying to do a regex match here for email format . here the result should be zero and email_id field should pass validation. But in my code the input line is written in error log as it didnt pass the email format validation

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you the if condition worked out

Comment: @daturmgirl Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. Can the file contain an email address with more than 13 characters? Why don't you use `$3` to get the email address? With the example input you could use something like `awk -v 'n=[a-z]+@gmail.com' '$3 !~ "^" n "$" { printf "%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME, FNR, $0> "/dev/stderr" ; count++ } END {print count}' BNC_fixedwidth.txt`

Comment: Thanks Bodo My input file is a fixed width  file So cant  use column number . So i have only column start position and col length

Comment: @daturmgirl you can use column numbers for fixed width files. In gawk you'd set FIELDWIDTHS, in other awks you'd use a while(substr()) loop to get the fields. Once you add some sample input/output containing lines that both should and should not pass your comparison we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
awk -v startPos=16 -v len=13 -v pat='[[:blank:]][a-z]+@gmail\\.com[[:blank:]]' '
{ match($0, pat);
  if (RSTART+1>=startPos && RLENGTH-2<=len){ print; "or do whatever you want..." }
}' infile
```

I added `[[:blank:]]` to the beginning and the end of the mail regex to match on single Space/Tab at the edge of *`pat`*, so with that it will cause startPos set to be 15 and len set be 15 (two more character length due to the `[[:blank:]]`, one at first and the next one at the end) when matching with `match()` function, if any match found, awk will set RSTART and RLENGTH variables; then you see we added 1 to RSTART to become 16 as the startPos is and deducted 2 from the RLEGNTH to become 13 for the len checking.

Input:

```
11111  20033t  abc@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
22222  20033t  abcd@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
33333  20033t   bf@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
44444  20033t  sda@invld.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
55555  20033t  4bf@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
66666  20033t xdbf@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
77777  20033t  a@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
88888  20033t  @gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
```

Output:

```
11111  20033t  abc@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
33333  20033t   bf@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
77777  20033t  a@gmail.com 19519  11/18/2021 12:06:10.260 PM BNC HardB 5 User Unk 125
```

If you strictly want to match the mail exactly start at position 16 and with the length of 13, replace both comparison operators with `==`.